# PCB trace impedance

Tags: pcb, microstrip

I have designed a GCPW trace with an impedance of 50 ohms (for a 5GHz application.) The trace is laid on a PCB with the dielectric as FR4 material.

I terminated one end of the trace with 50 ohms and measured the characteristics of the trace (from 100MHz - 5GHz) with VNA. I found that the impedance varies wildly with frequency as shown in the following figure.

[image: Real and imaginary part of impedances of the trace]

I observe that the matching is nowhere close to 50 ohm at all.

Following are my thoughts on what could be the reason for this:

- The periods that we see in the plots are roughly 1.2 GHz which seem to correspond to the length of the trace (94 mm.) This periodicity could happen due to the slight impedance mismatch resulting in multiple reflections.
- Skin effect occurs at high frequency bringing the surface roughness (at the metal-dielectric interface) into play resulting in an impedance mismatch. But this doesn't explain the low-frequency behavior.

Could you please comment on what is causing these oscillations in impedance?

Comment: Ultimate stupid question:  Was the trace terminated with 50 ohms, or was it open?

Comment: It is terminated with 50 ohm.

Comment: It is High-Tg FR4? Standard FR4 is pretty terrible (lossy) at high frequencies, and varies in Dk as the trace goes over the course weave. Also I assume your VNA was properly calibrated?

Comment: Yes, The VNA is calibrated properly with the Electronic calibration module. In my design, the traces are on a 4 layer board of which I am using the first and second layers for the traces(prepreg as the dielectric). The prepreg is Tg 130 and the core is Tg150.

Comment: Looks like you're having issues across the full band that you've swept, not just at 5 GHz.  Can you provide the actual PCB material used (FR4 is a generic term)?  Can you also provide details on your GCPW trace with full dimensions and pictures of the actual layout?

Comment: what's 'an impedance of 50 ohms' for the termination? A 50 ohm resistor? A 50 ohm load on a connector? A 20dB SMA pad? What are the dimensions of your line?

Comment: Please show the calculations you used to design the trace geometry. A photo of your board and termination might also be helpful to see if the real product matches the design you modeled

Comment: For termination, I used a 50 ohm RF terminators. I will make the question more clear add all the details about my design in a short while.

Comment: It seems like the characteristic impedance of your line is much lower than 50 Ohms. Perhaps in the order of 20 Ohms. A practical way to measure it is by taking the geometric mean of the impedance measured by your VNA when the line is terminated with a short and with an open.

Comment: If you’re familiar with Smith charts think about what you would see if your line is terminated with an impedance higher than the characteristic impedance as you change the distance from the load in terms of wavelength fraction. The trajectory will be a circle around the characteristic impedance, what is consistent with your results.

Comment: @Manideep Could you please add the details you said you would? This is a very interesting question and I'd be thrilled to find out more. Many thanks!